# Can I add a second processor to pi 4b 8gb? Is it even possible?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, hardware

I want to get more than the most possible performance out of my pi 4b.  I was looking around, and I saw it was possible to get just the processing unit for the pi 4 without the rest of the pi.  I looked on the web, and I found NOTHING even close to "how to add a second processor to a pi 4b".  Is it even possible? If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be extremely difficult if not impossible. There is no provision on the Pi 4b board for a second chip, and the hardware isn't designed to support a second chip.

One reasonable approach to increasing Pi computing power (for certain computations) would be to purchase several Pi4 boards and set them up with [HTCondor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTCondor) or a [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster)-like configuration.

Comment: Can I use the normal raspberry pi os or ubuntu?

Comment: I would suggest doing a search to see what others have done. Clustering RPis is usually done as an academic exercise or as a convenient software development system...

Comment: I found a tutorilal on how to do it. Thanks!